# `this` operator in c++?

Tags: c++, object

Sorry not sure if this has been asked before, I really dont know what to look up either. I'm new to C++ from Java. When we want to call a function on an object in Java, we say `picture.rotateRight();`

Then, in `rotateRight()`, we'd have something like `int height=this.getHeight();`. However, how do we do this in C++? I have a method named `invertcolors();` and then I have something like:

```
Image* myImage = new Image();
bool b = myImage->ReadFromFile("in_01.bmp");
myImage->invertcolors();

void invertcolors(){
    int width=TellWidth();
    int height=TellHeight();
    ...
}
```

How do I access `myImage` from the method definition without actually saying `myImage` (since that name can later be changed).

Also, the function parameters are non-negotiable.

Comment: Do you have [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/)?  If not, you really should get one.  It's all but impossible to learn to write correct C++ without one.

Comment: If you're new to C++, forget that you learned Java, [pick up a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read through it, as James McNellis have already mentioned.

Comment: @James McNellis: Well, it's still very hard, even with a good introductory book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your `invertcolors()` function definition is a non-member function. Although you've declared it inside the `Image` class, you haven't linked the implementation to the class in any way so the compiler thinks its a non-member function. To make it a member of `Image`, you need to use `Image::invertcolors` like this:

```
void Image::invertcolors(){
    int width=TellWidth();
    int height=TellHeight();
    ...
}
```

You do get `this` in C++, but it's a pointer so you have to use `this->getHeight()` in C++. However, note that it is redundant in this case. As a beginner you'll probably find the only real use in a method having the same argument name as an attribute. In this case, you'll need to use `this->height = height` for example. However, note that C++ has a nice syntax addition here. This code does the same as a simple setter:

```
void Image::setHeight(int height): height(height) {}
```

Note that neither in Java nor C++ is `this` an operator. `.`, `->` and `+` are examples of operators.

Comment: I tried this but I ge these errors: `error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function`

Comment: @mohabitar: You need to make `invertcolors()` a member of the `Image` class (both its declaration *and* its definition). Again, please [pick up a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), which will cover how to properly work with classes.

Comment: @mohabitar: The compiler thinks `invertcolors()` is a non-member function, so it's not in the `Image` class. Can you edit your question to include the `Image` class declaration so we can see what's up with it?

Comment: @mohabitar Note the `Image::` as in my example. You might be missing this.

Comment: @mohabitar: For your member function definition you would write `void Image::invertcolors()` in your first code snippet. You must specify which class the function declaration belongs to, otherwise it's a non-member function. Again, I deplore you to pick up a good C++ book and read through it. [Here's a link to a list of books recommended by the Stack Overflow community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You're struggling with rather basic C++; learn it right or you will struggle with the rest of C++.

Comment: @marcog: I don't think you can use a *ctor-initializer-list* except on constructors.  What compiler accepts this?

Comment: Ok I think that did the trick, but I gotta do more testing. Do we always have to use ::, even if the functions are already declared under the Image class?

Comment: @mohabitar: Yes, if you want to declare and define the member functions separately, you have to tell the compiler that they both belong to the `Image` class. You do that by putting the method declaration within the `Image` class itself, and putting `Image::` before the method name in the definition. I'm going to say this again: please pick up [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) and read it. It'll tell you how to deal with classes in C++ and much more. (By the way, do not buy any C++ books from Herbert Schildt. His C++ books are garbage.)

Comment: @mohabitar: If you put the function definition inside the class definition, like Java, you don't need to qualify it with `Image::`.  If the declaration is outside the class body, you will need to qualify with the class name (and maybe also namespace, nested class, etc.)

Comment: Ok I'm still a bit confused. I have this image, and using the EasyBMP library, I can access its individual RGB values using `greenValue=Image(x,y)->Green;`. However, since I cant use the name Image, I tried `greenValue=this->(x,y)->Green;`, but that didnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mohabitar: Is this a class you wrote, or someone else's?  If you want to call an operator on your own class, it gets pretty ugly.  Best thing to do is create a reference, like: `Image& self = *this; self(x, y);`.  Without the reference, you'll need something like `(*this)(x, y)`.  Oh now I see, you've got a class that inherits the existing BMP class.  The syntax I'm suggesting will work for invoking operators defined in the base class as well.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a keyword, not an `operator`, and it does exist in C++.  It's a pointer, so you'll use it with `->`, not `.`, when accessing members.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a member function, `this->whatever` is implicit, so you can just use `whatever` on its own, and the compiler will figure out that you mean `this->whatever`. There are a few cases (mostly in templates) that it can make sense to use `this->` in C++ as well, but it's only rarely necessary (I'm aware of the times, but after writing C++ for a couple of decades, I can probably still count the times I've done it on my fingers).

If your code is not in a member function, then it has to explicitly refer to some particular object (much as in Java).

Answer (score 0):

"this" is also available in C++. It's a pointer to the object on which the function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see the part about the parameters. New Answer: If the function parameters are non-negotiable, and you can't be arsed to define invertColors as a member function for Image (by extending the Image class) then you'll need a globally defined variable.

Outside of your main function, declare Image* myimg;

then use myimg like normal inside your function.

ex:

```
Image* myImg;
int main()
{
    ..all your initialization, etc. 
    invertColors();
}

void invertColors()
{
     int width = myImg->width;
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `invertcolors()`, `TellWidth()`, and `TellHeight()` are member functions of the `Image` class, it will work just as you've written it.

In C++, `this` is a const-pointer to the object on which the method was invoked (as opposed to Java, where `this` is a reference).  So, rather than:

```
this.doSomething(); // in Java
```

you'd say:

```
this->doSomething(); // in C++.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments, are you missing how to define the method:

Header file: Image.h

```
class Image : public BMP {

public:

    void invertcolors();
};
```

Source file Image.cpp

```
void Image::invertcolors()
{
    int width=TellWidth();
    int height=TellHeight();
    // ...
}
```